# Local morph on body parts of human model using webgl

Tags: javascript, three.js

My project needs local deformation on human model body parts. I saw a very good example with three.js that does exactly that: https://github.com/fashiontec/bodyapps-viz. Now the issue is that the model which comes with the example is not representative of all the people who might use this application. I want to make this example more general so that people can shape their avatar looking close to them. For this I manually created new obj files with equal number of faces and vertices in Makehuman. Now I want to plug those models in this woking example. The model that has been provided with webgl example comes in js file as a list of vertices coordinates, normals coordinates, faces (with vertex numbers). I tried to get my obj file in similar format and plug the values in. For some reason it still wont work and I get an error in three.js library while loading the model.

`TypeError: aa is undefined
three.js(line 489, col 452)`

I am looking for approaches I can have to use my models with this example. What other ways do I have other than simple copy-paste?

Comment: googled that error and came across this issue : [link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/658), maybe it helps

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the link does not help much, Basically things get screwed up when I put new face numbers in there. The code is very cryptic for me with huge libraries used for real time deformation of mesh with changes in sliders,  and I am unable to figure out why things go wrong. I am open to other ideas/ examples/ projects too on achieving the above goal.

Comment: Use the un-minified version of three.js to get an easier to understand error